# Why is polynomial regression considered a kind of linear regression?

Tags: statistics, regression

Why is polynomial regression considered a kind of linear regression?

This is what I mean by polynomial regression. For example, the hypothesis function is

$$h(x; t_0, t_1, t_2) = t_0 + t_1 x + t_2 x^2 ,$$

and the sample points are

$$ (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots$$

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/1882#1882).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a form of linear regression because it takes the form

$$h(x)=\sum_i t_if_i(x)\;,$$

which is a linear combination of functions $f_i(x)$ and is amenable to a solution using only linear algebra. The non-linearity of the functions $f_i(x)$ doesn't complicate the solution; it enters only in calculating the values $f_i(x_j)$, and everything is then linear in these values. What's important is that the function is linear in the parameters $t_i$; otherwise these need to be determined by non-linear optimization.

Comment: +1 despite the fact that no one's upvoted _my_ answer yet.  (But don't read the foregoing comment!)  Joriki, if you're in Berlin it must have been about 5:00 AM where you are when you answered.  Do you get up that early or do you go to bed at 5:30 AM and sleep until maybe.... 2:00 PM or so?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I used to do both at the time, but I've developed more regular sleeping patterns since :-)

Comment: A REAL computer geek stays on ALL the time!

Answer (score 13):

Everything in "polynomial regression" for which linearity matters is linear.  In linear regression, the vector of least-squares estimators $\widehat\alpha,\widehat\beta,\widehat\gamma,\ldots$ depends in a linear way on the vector of response variables $y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_n$.  The response variables are in effect treated as random and the predictor variables are in effect treated as fixed, i.e. non-random.  That can make sense despite the fact that if you take a new sample, both the response variables and the predictor variables change.  The reason for that is that you're interested in the *conditional* distribution of the response variable *given* the predictor variable.

So say we have
$$
y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_i + \alpha_2 x_i^2 + \mathrm{error}_i,
$$
We observe the $x$s and the $y$s and then we find the least-squares estimates $\widehat\alpha_0,\widehat\alpha_1,\widehat\alpha_2$.  Then we take a new sample with the same $x$s but instead of the $y$s we have $w_1,\ldots,w_n$, and we again find least-squares estimates; call them $\widehat\beta_0,\widehat\beta_1,\widehat\beta_2$.  Now suppose in place of the response variables we put $y_1+w_1,\ldots,y_n+w_n$, and again find the least-squares estimators.  What do we get?  The answer is just $\widehat\alpha_0+\widehat\beta_0,\widehat\alpha_1+\widehat\beta_1,\widehat\alpha_2+\widehat\beta_2$.  That's linearity.  (A similar proposition applies to scalar multiples.)

We want to know about the probability distribution of the least-squares estimates when we know the joint probability distribution of the $y$s.  Linearity makes that easy.