# Is there any measure for detecting quadratic or cubic relationships?

Tags: correlation

Correlation coefficients is a useful measure for detecting linear relationships.

Is there any measure for detecting linear relationship between one dependent variable and more than one independent variables?

Is there any measure for detecting quadratic or cubic relationships?

Moreover, there is a question and an answer in [quadratic relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308099/quadratic-relationship), could anyone explain more about the answer? why is it true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Joint_cumulants

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Is the proof of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308099/quadratic-relationship answer possible with the help of Cumulant concept?