# least squares regression parabola

Tags: statistics

In my AP Stats course, we just finished our chapter on least squares regression lines and are moving on to non-linear regressions. I was expecting a least squares regression parabola, but instead we are using logs to make the function linear.

I googled it and found  [this](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/trigonometry/6e/shared/appendix/regression.pdf) and [this](http://www.efunda.com/math/leastsquares/lstsqr2dcurve.cfm) on the least squares regression parabola and [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZzGG3fbj7AIC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=least+squares+regression+parabola+on+a+TI-84&source=bl&ots=L6v-aizE95&sig=He1_v6h9F3wNvfkYennQIW3Fn50&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HXh9UpLmMJSQkAfxzoHoBA&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=least%20squares%20regression%20parabola%20on%20a%20TI-84&f=false) how to use it on my calculator.

Is there a reason why my teacher and my book would not know/teach us about it? Is it a knew concept? Is using taking the log more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different kinds of non-linear regression, but fitting a parabola by least squares is **not** one of them.

Say you have data points $(x_i,y_i),\quad i=1,\ldots,n$ and you find the values of $a,b,c$ that minimize the sum of squares $\sum_{i=1}^n (ax_i^2 +bx_i +c - y_i)^2$.  **That is linear regression, not non-linear regression.**  It is a commonplace mistake to think that the reason why linear regression is called linear is that one is fitting a line.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75959/why-is-polynomial-regression-considered-a-kind-of-linear-regression/75966#75966).