# Line Of Regression given x?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

You have found the regression line for a set of data points to be: ŷ = 30.23x + 173.52. Use the line to predict the value of y when x = 48.

Comment: I don't remember finding that particular regression line...

Comment: The answer posted by @Quasar below is extremely misleading.

Comment: Really looks like a homework problem I wouldn't want to contribute to

Answer (score 2):

Plug $x=48$ into the original equation:
$$\hat y = 30.23(48)+173.52$$
$$\hat y = 1624.56$$

Answer (score 2):

The "fitted regression line" - the one that you provided - is the one that, when given an x value, will provide (if it's a good regression!) the best **estimate** of y.

Thus, for any possible value of x, you can simply plug it into the regression equation and find an **estimate** (that's what the hat means, usually!) for y. There should be hats over 30.23 and 173.52 when they are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, or other stand-ins for your regression intercept and coefficient, too, because they're **estimated** parameters obtained from your ordinary least squares regression.

Edited for clarity/correction thanks to comment from @michael hardy.

Comment: If you say $\hat y=\hat\alpha x+\hat\beta$, and find that $\hat\alpha = 30.23$, then one should _not_ write $\widehat{30.23}$. The number $30.23$ is a based on observed data; it is a statistic. The parameter $\alpha$, on the other hand, is unobservable; it is _not_ a statistic. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

We may predict that, for $x=48$, then
$$
ŷ = 30.23 \times \color{blue}{48} + 173.52 =\color{blue}{1624.56.}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick overview of what you mean, by regressing $y$ on $x$.

**Linear regression** essentially tries to establish a **straight-line** relationship between a variable of interest $y$ and a factor $x$ (sometimes multiple factors $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}$) that is(are) believed to explain(cause) $y$.

Linear regression assumes that $y$ is a linear function of $x$. Any $y_{i}$ can be computed, if $x_{i}$ is known.

$y_{i}=a+bx_{i}$

As an example, you believe that the **average returns** on **Google's stock** trading on the stock exchange has a significant relationship to the **average returns** on the **S&P 500** stock index.

Let's denote,

The expected annual returns on Google's stock by $E(R_{google})$.

The expected annual returns on the S&P500 index by $E(R_{market})$.

You would then *study* the *historical data* of Google's stock returns, say over the last 25 years and likewise the S&P 500 index returns for the past 25 years. In reality, you are collecting a **sample**.

Since we are performing linear regression, we assume that $E(R_{google})$ is a linear function of $E(R_{market})$.

$E(R_{google})=a+\beta\cdot{E(R_{market})}$

Using the sample data, mathematicians then use a method like **Ordinary Least Squares**(OLS) to **estimate** the coefficients $a$ and $\beta$. You would then arrive at an equation like (I just mocked it up),

$E(R_{google})=4+(1.2){E(R_{market})}$

or like the one you gave us,

$\hat{y}=30.23x+173.52$

Graphically, this is equivalent of plotting the sample data - the set of $(x_{i},y_{i})$'s with $E(R_{market})$ on the X-axis, and $E(R_{google})$ on Y-axis and passing a straight line through these points which is the best fit.

Once you've built a regression model, you could predict the dependent variable $y$ for any value of the independent variable $x$. You forecast $y$ by simply plugging in the x-value in the regression equation.

Regression is used in various disciplines to study different phenomena e.g. man-power planning a company, predicting inflation in an economy, predicting the long-run exchange rates, predicting the volatility of option prices, predicting the energy demands given the temperature and day of the year etc.

Comment: This answer is quite incorrect.  Linear regression is not about fitting straight lines; that's only one special case.  The assumption that the reason it is called "linear" is that one fits a line is false.  See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75959/why-is-polynomial-regression-considered-a-kind-of-linear-regression/75966#75966) explaining why fitting polynomials by least squares is considered a form of _linear_ regression. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy, you are quite right. Thanks, I will edit my answer.