# R Squared in polynomial multipleregrssion

Tags: polynomials, regression, linear-regression

In a linear regression, we can use R-Squared to check if a model fits

But what if I have a polynomial regression with to variable $var_1$ and $var_2$ and a model that goes like $$y=x_0+ x_1\cdot var_1 + x_2\cdot var_1^2 + x_3\cdot var_2 + x_4\cdot var_2^2$$

can we use r squared to check if fits well (or adjusted r squared)

i looked up and find both answers, yes and no...

also can we say that  $$y=x_0+ x_1\cdot var_1 + x_2\cdot var_2$$ is a simple linear regression and use r squared?

if no, how can we check if a polynomial regression fits well?

Comment: Without seeing your data it is hazardous to suggest anything, but I might consider whether a term $x_5\mathrm{var}_1 \mathrm{var}_2$ should be included. $\qquad$

Comment: One thing to consider in judging goodness of fit or its lack is whether any pattern is visible in the residuals. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to think that polynomial regression is not linear regression:

[Why is polynomial regression considered a kind of linear regression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75959/why-is-polynomial-regression-considered-a-kind-of-linear-regression)

It would also be a mistake to think that just by looking at $R^2$ you can tell whether a model fits.  The value of $R^2$ may be used in a significance test if you also know the sample size, but what is significant depends on the sample size.

The value of $R^2$ does tell you how much of the variability in the response variable is explained by the model.

Comment: if my sample size is 20 000 observations? is it enough to use r²? also if i have a polynomial regression like x0+ x1*var1 + x2*var1² + x3*var2 + x4*var2²
and a r² adjusted of 65%. Can i say that the model fits? and what is a way to say if the model fits if i can't use r squared?

Comment: also the fact that there is two variable var1 and var2 still makes x0+ x1*var1 + x2*var1² + x3*var2 + x4*var2² a linear regression? I couldn't tell from that link

Comment: @pengj : One can validly use $R^2$ in some kinds of hypothesis tests even with small samples, but the value of $R^2$ that would be significant evidence against the null hypothesis depends on the sample size.

Comment: but is a 20000 sample size enough?